# Cannot read property replace of null method parameter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I started messing around with Vue.js earlier this week.

So far I created a list of MTG(a TCG) cards. The data comes from the database through an Ajax request. This all works like a charm.

What i want to do next is replace the string that contains the costs of a card e.g. something like '{1}{U}{G}' with images for the corresponding tag.

HTML:

```
        <div v-for="(cards, key) in mainBoard" class="">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">@{{ key }}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ManaCost</th>
                @if($deck->enableCommander())
                    <th>Commander</th>
                @else
                    <th></th>
                @endif
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="card in cards">
                <td>@{{card.pivot.quantity}}</td>
                <td>@{{card.name}}</td>s
                <td v-html="replaceManaSymbols(card)"></td>
                @if($deck->enableCommander())
                    <td>
                        <span v-if="card.pivot.commander" @click="preformMethod(card, 'removeCommander', $event)"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></span>
                        <span v-else @click="preformMethod(card,'assignCommander', $event)"><i class="far fa-flag"></i></span>
                    </td>
                @else
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                @endif
                <td>
                    <button @click="preformMethod(card,'removeCardFromDeck', $event)"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                    <button @click="preformMethod(card,'plusCardInDeck', $event)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                    <button @click="preformMethod(card,'minusCardInDeck', $event)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Vue.js

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#Itemlist',
    data: {
        mainBoard: [],
        sideBoard: [],
    },
    methods:{
        preformMethod(card, url){
            var self = this;
            var varData = {
                slug: '{{ $deck->slug }}',
                card: card.id,
                board: card.pivot.mainboard
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/vue/'+url,
                data: varData,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.mainBoard = data.mainBoard;
                    self.sideBoard = data.sideBoard;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        },
        replaceManaSymbols(card){
            var mc = card.manaCost;
            var dump = mc.replace(/([}])/g, '},').split(',');
            var html = '';

            /**
             * replace each tag with an image
             */
            return html;
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        var self = this;
        var varData = {
                slug: '{{ $deck->slug }}'
            };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/vue/getDeckList',
            data: varData,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                self.mainBoard = data.mainBoard;
                self.sideBoard = data.sideBoard;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

I pass the card as a parameter to the `replaceManaSymbols` method. I can console.log the contents of mana without any issue. But as soon as a want to modify the string Vue throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase/split/replace' of null`. I'm not really sure what's going wrong. Any idea's?

Comment: you `return card.manaCost;` first? if this is the case, string modification  is never supposed to happened

Comment: Aah my bad. That's still part of the debugging, ill edit

Comment: anyway it looks like `card.manaCost` is null. pls try to console.log it ?

Comment: Logging card.ManaCost returns a ``{2}{U}{U}`` as it should. But trying to execute something like split on it doesn't work

Comment: hmm... all `card.manaCost` in the for loop is not null ?

Comment: Yup. The land cards have a null manaCosts. Didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't use methods on the display side. Keep them for the update side - processing changes back into a store and such. Methods aren't reactive - they need to be called. You want your display to automatically reflect some underlying data, so you should use computed.

You should also avoid using v-html, because you end up with markup outside your templates, and that markup is static. It's not totally clear to me what will be in v-html, but you should try and keep markup in your template, and inject values using data, props or computed. Hope this helps!

If you want a div with some text that magically turns into an image tag, this could be a good use for `<component :is>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Altho it isn't always 1 image that has to be inserted. It one image per ``{X}``. Would that also work with ``component :is``?

I found the solution i currently have quite pretty and readable. Especially in comparison to Jquery I had before